# Is there a mistake in my sentences? (inversion)

Tags: inversion, adverbials

**Inversion to emphasize a negative or limiting adverbial**

1.We didn't discover the mistake until much later.

Ans: Not until much later did we discover the mistake.

2.Nowadays People no longer go by sea.

Ans:No longer do people go by sea.

Comment: They look OK to me. What are your concerns?

Comment: Not sure about the second one

Comment: I'd say it's OK in the right context.

Comment: I don't think it's a very good idea to spend too much time on exercises like this. The first inversion here is perfectly "reasonable" English - but it's more accurate to say the effect is "poetic / literary" than "emphatic". But the *second* example  is *extremely* "poetic / stilted". It's difficult to imagine a context where a non-native speaker might be likely to use it "correctly".

Answer (score 0):

Side note: "People" in the second sentence should not be capitalized. "Nowadays people no longer go by sea."

I take it these are sentences from some sort of test? Without knowing exactly what the question was, I can't say which of each pair is better. All four sentences are grammatically correct and understandable. The first sentence in each pair is the more normal way to express the idea. The second sentence in #1 is an unusual word order that could emphasize the "not until much later". The second sentence in #2 is understandable but definitely unusual wording -- more what I'd expect to see in song lyrics or a poem than ordinary writing. But valid.